# qtcreator is not starting in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, ubuntu-16.04

I'am using Ubuntu 16.04 version.i have installed QtCreator using the command

`sudo apt-get install QtCreator`

when i tried to start qt in terminal by typing the command **sudo qtcreator** it is giving following error

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "xcb". Reinstalling the application may fix this
>   problem. Aborted (core dumped)

what is the solution?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

Comment: Try this command:                                                                                    
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/

Comment: qt5 folder is doesn't  contains plugins it is empty

Comment: See this answer for help with debugging plugin errors in Qt Creator: https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without